Find  in the triangle below.
In the figure calculate . (Answer:$15^o $)
I try:
$ \angle ABC \cong \angle BCA  = 45^o $
$\angle ABD = 45^o -15^o = 30^o \implies \angle ADB =60^o + \alpha $
$ \angle BAD = 90^o -\alpha$
$\angle ADC = 180^o -2\alpha$
How do I finish?


Use the angles in the triangle BDC.

Yes...as always great resolutions..thanks

The following is your diagram with the line $EF$ ($E$ on $BC$ and $F$ on $AC$), going through $D$ and perpendicular to $AC$, added.

Since $\measuredangle FCE = 45^{\circ}$, then $\measuredangle CEF = 45^{\circ}$ and
$$\measuredangle BED = 135^{\circ}, \;\; \measuredangle BDE = 180^{\circ} - 15^{\circ} - 135^{\circ} = 30^{\circ}$$
For somewhat easier algebra, let $\lvert AB\rvert = \lvert AC\rvert = x$. As $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle FEC$, with a side lengths similarity ratio of $2:1$, we get
$$\lvert BC \rvert = \sqrt{2}x \;\;\to\;\; \lvert BE \rvert = \frac{\lvert BC\rvert}{2} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Using the Law of sines with $\triangle BDE$ then gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(135^{\circ})} & = \frac{\lvert BE\rvert}{\sin(30^{\circ})} \\
\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & = \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\lvert BD\rvert & = x
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Thus, $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles. Since $\measuredangle ABD = 30^{\circ}$, then
$$\measuredangle BAD = \frac{180^{\circ} - 30^{\circ}}{2} = 75^{\circ} \;\land\; \measuredangle BAD = 90^{\circ} - \alpha \;\;\to\;\; \alpha = 15^{\circ}$$

Thans my friend..I think this is it..

Just one correction: sin $135^o$ and not $sen 145^o$

@petaarantes You're welcome. Also, thanks for pointing out the typo, which I've now corrected.


In figure we have:
$\angle ABD=30\Rightarrow Arc AD=30^o$
CA is tangent on the circle so we have:
$\alpha=\angle DAC=\frac{Arc AD}2=\frac{30}2=15^o$
Note that $BD=AB$ must be included in the statement.

Thanks for solution. The original question does not include BD= AB...that way the problem would be very simple. I think there may be another way

@petaarantes, The author of question indirectly hints that  AB=BD by giving the answer, because only in this case $\alpha=15^o$. We are free to assume various cases including $AB=BD$ to solve the problem.This is what I did. Another method is to show the case  by calculations, that is what Omielan did.

But I can't use the answer to determine the resolution. In a test, simply stating that one segment is equal to the other would not be valid. I always need to demonstrate algebraically the statements that are made, as John demonstrated.

Then any value can be the answer, that is why I said AB=BD must be mentioned in statement. The author said the answer instead.Better statement  is when $\alpha$ is put in place of $15^o$ in figure.

The following is your diagram with the line $DE$ (with $E$ on $AC$) perpendicular to $AC$, and $BD$ extended to meet $AC$ at $F$, added.

Since $\measuredangle ABF = 30^{\circ}$, then $\measuredangle BFA = 60^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle EDF = 30^{\circ}$, i.e., both $\triangle ABF$ and $\triangle DEF$ are $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangles. For simpler algebra, have
$$\lvert AB\rvert = x \;\;\to\;\; \lvert AE\rvert = \frac{x}{2}, \;\; \lvert EF\rvert = y \;\;\to\;\; \lvert DF\rvert = 2y$$
Next, using the triangle ratios in $\triangle ABF$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{3} & = \frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{\lvert AF\rvert} \\
\sqrt{3} & = \frac{x}{\frac{x}{2} + y} \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} + \sqrt{3}y & = x \\
\sqrt{3}y & = x - \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} \\
y & = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{x}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Next, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert BF\rvert & = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\lvert AB\rvert \\
\lvert BD\rvert + \lvert DF\rvert & = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\lvert BD\rvert + 2\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{x}{2}\right) & = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\lvert BD\rvert + \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}} - x & = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\lvert BD\rvert & = x
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Thus, as in my other answer, this shows $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles. Since $\measuredangle ABD = 30^{\circ}$, then
$$\measuredangle BAD = \frac{180^{\circ} - 30^{\circ}}{2} = 75^{\circ} \;\land\; \measuredangle BAD = 90^{\circ} - \alpha \;\;\to\;\; \alpha = 15^{\circ}$$
