Find $\angle \alpha$ In the triangle ABD below.
In the figure calculate $\alpha$ ($AB=AD$)
(Answer: $15^o$)

I try:
$\angle CAD = 90-\alpha$
$\angle ACD = 180^o -(90^o -\alpha) - 2\alpha = 90^o -\alpha$
$ \therefore \triangle ADC_{(isosc.)}$
$ \angle BCD  = 3\alpha + 90^o $
$ \angle ACB = 180^o -2\alpha$
How do I finish?

This question is similar to: Find  in the triangle below.. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

How is different than you question yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4950545/find-in-the-triangle-below ?

@Andrei If you pay attention, the angles are different and the triangle is not an isosceles rectangle. The problem requires another type of solution.

@Andrei The statement is very clear...nothing to change...I accept suggestions

There must be something wrong: $\alpha$ could have any value without additional info.

@Intelligentipauca    You are right...he would need to say that AB = AD...I will correct the statement so that the solution is possible.

$\angle CAD=90^o−α$ and $\angle DCA=180^o−(\angle CAD+2α)=90^o−α$,
$△ADC$ is isosceles.
By symmetry: $△DCE$ is equilateral
$\therefore 2\alpha+60^o=90^o⟹α=15^o$
(Solution:Pie)

